# check if href button clicked then execute code in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use this code to create  button which has href link. how its possible to know when it clicked in order to execute  specific code in php... help appreciated.

```
echo  "<a type="button" href='http://www.facebook.com' value="facebook" target="_blank" class="button">Go to facebook</a>";
```

Comment: ***onclick = "function()"*** and then make an ajax request on the function.

Comment: from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_type.asp) the `type` prop of an `<a/>` is intended for media types.

Comment: I think onclick is the better solution, but if SEO is important !!! you must use href and then return false with each clicks and handle redirect or requests with JavaScript to PHP file

Comment: Your quotation marks are wrong! If u are using echo " ...  " then set attributes in ' only. Your code should look like `echo  "<a type='button' href='http://www.facebook.com' value='facebook' target='_blank' class='button' onclick='my_function();'>Go to facebook</a>";`

Comment: there is an issue though. i need to use  pop up in combination with php and show some variable to check if the variable change...is this possible in the function?

Comment: ok found it <?php echo "alert('$variable');"; ?>

Comment: hmmm $variable not changing in function. only first time work any thoughts?